# How do i add a string to a data type that had html?

Tags: php, email

I'm creating a share page for my website. I want the user to be able to send a message along with the formatted html.

so I have.

```
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];

$page = 'some html code';

mail($TO,$subject,$page, $headers);
```

I want the `$message` and `$page` to be added together.

Comment: This is a bad idea, once you allow users to insert HTML into your webpage without regard to what they might put in to your page then it is no longer your page at all.

Comment: is your question "how to concatenate two strings" or "how to replace a string inside another" or "how to send html emails"? you know there is a "replace" method in php strings, and the double quotes to "evaluate vars inside string" can work too, leaving it to teh pros to shwo you how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to accomplish what (I think) you're trying to do.  The example might look like

```
$message = "I'm a message";

$page = <<<HTML
<p>I'm a $message that's been inserted into html.</p>
HTML;
```

Like other users have said before me, *never, ever* use input directly from a user without first sanitizing or filtering it.

Comment: Yes this is what i'd like to do. I tried doing what you've done here but in the email it just displays the variable $message not the message.

Comment: @creocare - Make sure to read the heredoc documentation (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) carefully.  I had some problems when I first started using it too ;) There are some very significant gotchas that may be causing you some issues. Pay special attention to the rules about the closing delimiter.

Would you consider posting the heredoc code that's giving you trouble? That might be helpful.

Comment: $message = $_REQUEST['message'];

$page =<<<'
   <html>
     <body>
       <p> $message </p>
         <img src="print.jpg"/>
     </body>
</html>';

Comment: I guess it should look like this?
<<<HTML
<html>
  <body>
   <p>$message</p>
   <img src="print.jpg">
  </body>
</html>';HTML

Comment: @creocare - It's hard to tell from the comment formatting, but it looks like you're not including the mandatory opening and closing delimiters.  heredoc must start with three less than symbols followed by the delimiter, ex <<<ABC.  At the end of your heredoc, ABC must appear again, all by itself, with no extra whitespace, etc.  You can add a semicolon.  Have you tried copying and pasting my heredoc example for test purposes?  Or the examples in the php docs?  That might help.

Comment: Yes! Make sure you end with HTML as well.

Comment: Yeah I did but it doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: one other question too. Why the the " ' " in that's screw up everything?

Comment: Why do you have a single quote and a colon before the closing HTML?  Is the closing HTML on a line all by itself?  I understand how confusing this can be, but make sure you've carefully reviewed the docs on this one.  Unless there's something really unconventional going on with your development environment, you should be able to use heredoc without a problem.

Comment: I should post the whole page somewhere so you can see it.

Comment: isn't there a website called postit or something for that?

Comment: i'm not sure if this is legit for this forum but. check it here. http://paste-it.net/public/v632c98/

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but it's obvious from your code sample that you're not taking my suggestions and not reading the php heredoc documentation closely enough.  Please review the heredoc documentation (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), paying special attention to the section titled WARNING in bold, red font, located in the box with the red border and red background.  The problem you're having is addressed in that section.

Comment: No worries. I see the error of what I was doing. I was able to make it work for the first IF statement. If I add a second heredoc it wrecks the whole thing. http://paste-it.net/public/v38693f/

Comment: I figured out a way to make it all work. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `$message .= $page;`

It is equivalent to "append `$page` to `$message`"

Answer (score 0):

If you just want do concatinate the two strings?

```
$body = $message . $page;
mail($TO,$subject,$body, $headers);
```

Example taken from http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

```
<?php
$a = "Hello ";
$b = $a . "World!"; // now $b contains "Hello World!"

$a = "Hello ";
$a .= "World!";     // now $a contains "Hello World!"
?>
```

Comment: Well that doesn't seem to be working. How can I insert $message into the html?

Answer (score 0):

I would **strongly** advise you to sanitize the user input beforehand.

just do the following it should work:

```
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];

$message .= 'some html code';

mail($TO,$subject,$page, $headers);
```

The `.` is a concatenation operator and you can read more about it [here.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: Can you explain a little "sanitize"?

Comment: Do not trust the user. Assume that every user is malicious(morbid thought but very handy). So essentially, you have to verify all the user input, to prevent things like SQL Injection, XSS attacks etc. Have a browse through the following:
http://devzone.zend.com/article/1113

Answer (score 0):

to answer the question here...

> Well that doesn't seem to be working.
>   How can I insert $message into the
>   html? – creocare

```
    $template = '<html>
            <body>
            <h1>A message from something.com</h1>
            <p>
            {{userMessage}}
            </p>
            </body
            </html>';

$userMessage = 'hey there im the message';
$message = str_replace( '{{userMessage}}', $userMessage, $template );
echo $message;
```

you can get you dynamic message into your html email template using str_replace